# При компиляции модели, получаю ошибку 'Unknown metric function:precision'

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

Всем привет,
Помогите разобраться с вопросом пожалуйста. 
Создал нейронную сеть. Компилирую ее по метрике 'precision' 
Вот код

```
def create_baseline_precision():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape = [44]))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adadelta',
                 loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
                 metrics = ['precision', 'recall'])
    return model
```

Далее запускаю модель по обычному флоу, который до этого работал при `metrics = ['accuracy']`

```
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_baseline_precision, epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)

scaler = MinMaxScaler((-1, 1))

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', scaler), 
    ('classifier', estimator)
])

y_true, y_pred = cross_val_predict_timeseries_splits(
    pipeline, X=X.values, y=y.values, cv=cv, 
    n_jobs=-1, flatten=True
)
```

Получаю ошибку: `Unknown metric function:precision`

Вместо 'precision' я пробовал использовать `tf.keras.metrics.Precision`, но ситуация не изменилась. 
Как правильно компилировать модель с использованием 'precision'?

Спасибо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076609/how-to-calculate-precision-and-recall-in-keras

Comment: @MaxU это тоже пробовал. не помогает

Comment: Здесь другая ошибка возникает: FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_2
  [[{{node Variable_2/read}}]]